# Is General Ticket valid in Sleeper class

Tags: trains, tickets, indian-railways

When travelling on Indian Railways, can I use a general ticket to get into a sleeper class compartment?

If not, and there is a sleeper berth available, how much is the supplement to pay on-board to the TTE to travel in SL.  Does this vary by journey, or is it the same on all trains?

Answer (score 2):

Now, I don't have an official source for you, but by news and some of the decent work Lalu Prasad Yadav actually did for the railways, I can tell you that you should **ideally be expected to pay the fare difference** and nothing else. This is of course only true if there are actually any empty berths available in the sleeper class.

If the TTE is corrupt, he might ask you for a bribe, but it's not the rule and even though I won't support bribery, but it's up to you in that case.

Comment: I checked what you said with a TTE. You are correct. If you pay the fare difference it is enough.